# ASP.net server event handled client-side

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, events

I was wondering if anyone had an easy way to wire up javascript event handlers to events happening on the server-side.  I have a long running process that includes a lot of steps, and would like the client to be continually updated with new information as the steps transition.  Will this involve some sort of polling mechanism?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3):

Send an AJAX or JSON request from the client every so often asking for `status.xml`.  Then, on the server, when something changes, just quickly write a new line to `status.xml` the same way you would to the console.  You can use `setInterval( function, timeBetweenRuns )` in Javascript to do this regularly.

Comment: Why not use session state instead of a file?

Comment: Feel free.  The sort of nuts-and-bolts implementation is up to you.

Comment: But won't polling the service, while it's synchronously blocking with the long running process not work?

Comment: this is why I suggested just printing a line to an XML file.  You can do that from your long running process, and then serve to the client not using ASP but as a simple flat HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible to use an update panel to do this with maybe a timer? it's sort of how I would do it.

Course, this depends on what you're doing already. I'm assuming you're using Forms...

Comment: UpdatePanels are a bit heavy for regular polling; especially when there's a lot of Viewstate. I'd go for PageMethods.

Comment: @Yellowfog - I agree they're heavy, like I said it just depends on what the effect is that he's aiming for. But I did forget about PageMethods...

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calling a Web Service is how I would do it.